# How can i add the jars in my lib folder as individual dependencies using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a legacy Java Webapp (Struts2), where all my dependencies are present in **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib** folder. I have tried to convert the entire project to Maven using Eclipse>Configure>Convert-to-Maven-Projet and new pom file was generated successfully.

How can i add the jars in my lib folder as individual dependencies in my `pom.xml` and manage them using `pom.xml`. I don't want to point to the lib folder during maven package and include the jars in my final war file, instead i would like to get rid of the all the jars in lib folder and manage them using `pom.xml`, just like any other Maven Project.

What is the best way to achieve this ? Is there any automated process or do i need to manually add dependencies in `pom.xml`? (FYI - all my jars are standard Java dependencies like Struts,Log4j,Apache Commons etc., so i can get them from Maven central repo).

Comment: Why don't you just add all the dependencies from the maven repo?

Comment: Completely unclear. It seems to me that you don't know how Maven works, BTW.

Comment: I can do that, but then i have to manually specify the info like group-id,artifact-id etc for all my 30 different jars in my pom.xml

Comment: @AndreaLigios to keep it simple, i dont want to add snippets like this for all my jars in Lib folder.

<dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

instead, i am curious to know if there is any automated process

Comment: It's a nonsense: to avoid a work that will cost you (in the worst case) 30 minutes, you want to "play Frankenstein" bypassing Maven standard mechanisms with some voodoo... it's 30 minutes not 30 days: go standard, go straight :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios You are right, mine is a small application so it takes 30minutes. However  I ain't trying to "play Frankenstein" I am just curious to know how these kind of scenarios are handled for large apps, so that i can leverage the same.

Comment: You are good in being curious, in not accepting anything for sure and in trying thinking laterally. That said, this *is* playing Frankenstein: Maven manages all your libraries for you, the only thing it asks to you is to specify name, version and group of the libraries. Then it'll be in charge of everything, transparently. Configure-and-forget. And you're trying to find a workaround to avoid writing this informations ? It's not a good search, IMHO. A large application could ask a couple of hours, but if you put *voodoos* in this, they could easily become a couple of months... of bugfixing

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thanks for the info. All these days i directly worked on existing maven projects just by adding or removing dependencies, managing versions,scope etc. This is my first task where i am converting a non maven proj. to maven proj. So am trying to explore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an automatted process to do that task for you, because jars can be included in different dependencies. You have to add them manually to your pom file.